# sort images by size with php and fill divs

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, gallery

I need your help please...

I'm having 4 equal size DIV's on the page. There're many images in the database and each of them have specified if it's portrait or landscape style, so each div should contain a single portrait style image or 2 landscape style images resized to fit in it, continuing filling other div's with the same manner.

Here's the similar example, but with only portrait style images - http://site.avtandil.com/index.php?pg_id=1128504689&pg_symbol=604280385

Lets say there're following records in the DB:

```
ID  Name    Style

01  1.jpg   Portrait
02  3.jpg   Landscape
03  4.jpg   Landscape
04  2.jpg   Portrait
05  5.jpg   Landscape
06  6.jpg   Landscape

...
```

They should follow sort order by ID, so first comes div with 1.jpg , then another div with 3.jpg and 4.jpg, then again div with only 2.jpg and another div with 5 and 6, continuing further.

The important thing is that there can be multiple wrapper divs with such 4 DIV's inside, depending on the total number of images.

I'd appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show some code. We don't write code for you, we just correct problems with code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually looking for the correct logic and will update as soon as will have some point where to start.